# How to compute the ramification indices in the degree-genus formula

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I've been study the proof of the genus formula and I am a little confused about the ramification index of one of the maps involved. Let $C$ be a projective algebraic curve in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ such that $[0,1,0] \notin C$. Define
$$\varphi: C \to \mathbb{C}P^1 $$
$$\varphi([x,y,z]) = [x,z] $$
Then $\varphi$ is a holomorphic map. I want to show that the ramification index $\varphi$ at $[a,b,c] \in C$ is the degree of the zero of the map $y \mapsto P(a,y,c)$ at $b$. The definition I know of ramification index is the smallest number $n$ such that the $n$-th derivative of the map (in a local chart) is non-zero at the point.

Take $p=[a,b,c]\in C$. Since $[0,1,0] \notin C$, we know that not both of $a,c$ are zero. Say $c\not = 0$. By Euler's relation, we know that at least one of $\partial P/\partial x,\partial P/\partial y$ is non-zero at $[a,b,c]$. The case where $\partial P/\partial y \not = 0$ is easy, so say $\partial P/\partial x \not = 0$. Then by the implicit function theorem we may write $y$ as a function of $x$. Since $c\not =0$, using the usual local coordinate on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ gives that our map $\varphi$ is given by $x \mapsto y(x)$ in local coordinates.

I'm not sure how to show that $y(x)$ has derivatives at $a$ as required. Elementary arguments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just checking... that you do know that the idea of (and actually a fully adequate definition of) "ramification index" of a (non-constant...) map from a curve to $\mathbb P^1$ at a point is the positive integer $n$ such that the map is locally isomorphic to $w\to w^n$.

Comment: @paulgarrett yes I've seen that definition and I'm comfortable with the equivalence of the two definitions